# Salvar array em CSV python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Eu escrevi o código abaixo para armazenar alguns dados em um dataframe, logo após converti ele em um array, mas quando salvo o mesmo no arquivo CSV, o mesmo pula linhas no arquivo salvo

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df1 = pd.read_csv("CSSS.csv",  encoding="UTF-8", sep=";", usecols=["CPF"])
df2 = pd.read_csv("CSSS.csv",  encoding="UTF-8", sep=";", usecols=["Login"])

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1)
df_array = df.values


with open("crl.csv", "wt") as csv_output:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_output, delimiter=";")
    writer.writerow(["CPF", "Login"])

    for d in df_array:
        writer.writerow(d)
```

segue como fica o arquivo CSV
[image: Arquivo CSV]

Answer (score 1):

Com o próprio `pandas` você pode fazer isso, ele ta função `to_csv` que faz exatamente o que você quer

```
df.to_csv("crl.csv",index=False,sep=";")
```

documentação e referencias:

[to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)

Comment: até facilitou, mas os dados são salvos em uma unica coluna separados apenas por virgula

Comment: ja consegui, obrigado pela dica utilizei o sep

Comment: df.to_csv("crl.csv", index=False, sep=";")

Comment: Massa cara, se a resposta te ajudou marca como a resposta  obs editei a resposta para se adequar sua situação